# Why did Emily's mother become angry on Jason's reply?

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, the-ultimate-gift

In The Ultimate Gift, there is a park scene (00:33:51), When Emily's mother came and ask for Jason's forgiveness on account of the fact that her daughter was disturbing him, Jason said "That's ok, I'm not the one who's disturbed". After that, Emily's reaction was angry, she said "Some friend you are, thanks a lot, poser." Why was she angry? Jason just said that he's not being disturbed.

Comment: I did not watch that so I post it as a comment. From that dialog excerpt, it seems to me that Jason is saying that Emily is disturbed, or her daugther, and this makes Emily angry.